# Outlook for Mac 15: Show unread count by day in conversation view

Tags: email, ms-office

In a previous version of outlook for Mac, there was a little bubble showing the unread count by day when viewing the messages arranged by conversation.

However, in Outlook for Mac 15.18, this unread count by day UI element no longer exists.

Is there some way to get that count to appear again?

[image]